# Older version showing on the login screen even after upgrade

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, versions, 22.10

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 22.04 to 22.10, first via the graphical *Software Updater* application (when it prompted me on its own for an upgrade to 22.10), and next via `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. I followed it up with `sudo do-release-upgrade`.

But still, I see 'ubuntu 22.04' displayed on my login screen. This gives me the impression that there could be more serious things that failed to get properly upgraded along with older stuff not getting properly removed.

The login screen does have the new, 22.10 wallpaper (of a stag/deer in line-art)

My `/etc/os-release` correctly shows 22.10.

Running `sudo do-release-upgrade` again gives the message, *'No new release found.'*

Comment: What you did does NOT upgrade a release, it only fully updates your current release.

Comment: `do-release-upgrade` upgrades to the next version.  However, if your updates are set for LTS only, it will not upgrade you to a non-LTS (22.10) release.

Comment: @Terrance  `do-release-upgrade` says *No new release found.* . My updates *are* set for all Ubuntu releases and not just LTS. Btw, I was prompted by the (graphical) *Software Updater* to upgrade, and I went through the whole graphical upgrade process which included (towards the end) removal of deprecated packages and such. That process completed without any issues.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Please see my comment-reply above to Terrance. I did go thru the Software Updater graphical application *first* when it prompted me to upgrade to 22.10.

Comment: @Terrance Also, my `/etc/os-release` shows 22.10. Is is possible to find out from where the string 22.04 is getting picked up to be overlaid on the wallpaper?

Comment: Please update your question with details and don't use comments.

Comment: It sounds like it upgraded, but didn't update the call to the right version on your login page.  You have a good question here and unfortunately, I might not have an answer for you but I did give you a +1 so maybe someone else might have experienced the same thing and will know how to fix it.  Sorry I am not much more help here.

Comment: I am facing the same issue i dont know how to fix.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue as you,changing the display manager from lighdm to gdm3
solved my issue.

Try following steps for that:

1. First of all check which display manager you have by running:

```
systemctl status display-manager
```

2. Install gdm3 along with gnome-session:

```
 sudo apt install gnome-session gdm3
```

3. Make gdm3 as default display manager:

```
 sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

When prompted select gdm3

4. Stop ligtdm

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

5. Start gdm3

```
 sudo service gdm3 start
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at https://packages.ubuntu.com/lunar/unity-greeter I notice that the version of unity-greeter for 23.04 (lunar) is still only 22.04-1-0ubuntu2, as it was also for 22.10. So if you look in /usr/share/unity-greeter you'll see "logo.png" which is the "ubuntu 22.04" displayed in the lower left of the login screen.

It just seems like unity-greeter hasn't been upgraded since 22.04, not even to change the version reported in logo.png.

See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-greeter/+bug/1997999

Looking at the source code there seems to be a "logo-generator.vala" so if you manage to get as far as compiling that, you can use it to generate your own logo:

./logo-generator --logo=../data/logo-bare.png --text="23.04" --output=logo.png